# The number of the union-intersection calculation results equals to the number of paths

Tags: combinatorics

Problem Statement:

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_{2k+1}$ be $2k+1$ generic sets. We insert $\cap$ and $\cup$ alternately between them, as $A_1\cap A_2\cup A_3\dots\cup A_{2k+1}$. The calculation results depend on how I add the parentheses, as $A_1\cap (A_2\cup A_3)$ generally does not equal to $(A_1\cap A_2)\cup A_3$. But sometimes different parenthesis may have same results, as $((A_1\cap A_2)\cup (A_3\cap A_4))\cup A_5$ equals to $(A_1\cap A_2)\cup ((A_3\cap A_4))\cup A_5)$. Among all possible ways to add the parentheses, how many distinct results (for general sets) are there? What about $2k$ sets?

I have written some code and looked for OEIS, and it turns out the $2k$-set case matches [A032349](https://oeis.org/A032349) and $2k+1$-set case matches [A027307](https://oeis.org/A027307). The description for the sequence is partially correct. Both of them are considering paths taking steps $(2,1),(1,2),(1,-1)$ and does not fall below $x$ axis, but [A032349](https://oeis.org/A032349) has wrong starting point and destination: it should be from $(0,1)$ to $(3k+1,0)$.

I have tried several ways to deal with this, such as deriving a recurrent formula for the number of results (as we deal with Catalan) or doing bijection (I have make the number of sets to some kind of trees). However, I failed.

One of my friends hinted [this literature](https://people.brandeis.edu/%7Egessel/homepage/students/drakethesis.pdf) as "schroder path" or "full ternary tree", but I cannot understand it...

Can anyone craft an easy-to-understand bijection or proof? Thank you all!

P.S. As @Henry pointed out there is another combinatorial interpretation of the sequence, which is [A084078](https://oeis.org/A084078). It is the length of generating sequences, starting from $[0]$ (see it as a python list), and every time we substitute each $k$ the values $-|k+1|,-|k+1|+2,\dots,|k-1|$. For example, initial is $[0]$, and the range for $0$ is $[-1,1]$, so $[0]$ becomes $[-1,1]$. Now for $-1$ the range is $[0,2]$ and for $1$ it is $[-2,0]$, so the sequence becomes $[0,2,-2,0]$. Then the sequence becomes $[-1,1,-3,-1,1,-1,1,3,-1,1]$, and so on. Now the question becomes more complecated... is there a (bijective, hopefully) proof for proving the number of these three items to be equal?

Comment: @Henry Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your friend may have been looking at something like [A006318](https://oeis.org/A006318).  I am not clear what initial terms of the sequence(s) you have found

Comment: @Henry Oh, the initial terms are the same (there are no offsets). That is, if there are $2k$ sets, it is the $k$ th term of A032349. If there are $2k-1$ terms, it is $k$th term of A027307.

Comment: So you are saying $1, 2, 4, 10, 24, 66,172, \ldots$ which seems to be [A084078](https://oeis.org/A084078) or [A137842](https://oeis.org/A137842).

Comment: @Henry That is right. Yes, if you join the two sequence together it is A137842. I split the odd and even case is because the starting and ending point are not the same. Thank you for finding another combinatorial implication as A084878 However, I still could not find the bijection and prove the relations though...

Comment: Here is a starting point. Each parenthesization results in a full binary tree (i.e. every internal node has both left and right child) where the leaves are labeled  with $A_i$, $i=1,\dots, n$, from left to right (i.e. alphabetically according to the sequence of directions of edges away from the root, $L$ before $R$) and internal nodes are labeled with $\cup$ or $\cap$. Then you need to figure out what restriction is imposed on the labels of the internal vertices by the $\cup/\cap$-alternating condition.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Thank you very much for the reply, I have previously thought about this way and the restriction is the doing the following: any $\cap$ node must have one or two $\cup$ nodes as its child and vice versa. This gives a kind-of (but not really) a recurrence sequence as it may also encode the rest of them are odd/even (i.e. two kinds of nodes, and two kinds of parity). So, because of the node's equivalence of odd and even (and not necessarily $\cup$ or $\cap$, actually) I made the following modification...

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein ... For a node labelled "even", the child is two "odd" (say, leftmost and rightmost) and several evens. For a node labelled "odd", the child has to be one odd (leftmost OR rightmost, so they are two different ways) and others are even, or it is a leaf. I tried to make it into binary (although nontrivial) but for binary one it seems to be more than two kinds of labels...

Comment: ↑Sorry in the last comment. If the label is odd, the odd child has to be leftmost. Back to binary: ...which we call them ''mature'' and ''immature''. An ''immature'' odd node split into a (left) mature even node and a odd node (both type), a ''mature'' odd node split into a odd node (both type) and a even node (both type) or a leaf.  An ''immature'' even node split into a ''mature'' even node and a even node (both type) and a ''mature'' even node split into two or node (both type for each). However, there are too many types and recurrence is hard to analyze, and bijection is even harder...

Comment: @JetfiRex Maybe the way to think about it is to consider it as plane trees instead. If the root $R$ of tree $T$ has children $T_1,\dots,T_k$, then we read the sequence $l(T)$ of $\cup/\cap$-labels as follows: $l(T)=(l(T_1),l(R),l(T_2),l(R),l(T_3),\dots,l(R),l(T_k))$. This means that we can ignore labels as long as we make sure that they alternate. This is equivalent to saying that the subtrees $T_2,\dots,T_{k-1}$ have an odd number of internal nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be an elegant solution, but it does the job.

We can map every parenthesization of $A_1\cap A_2\cup A_3\cap A_4\cup A_5\cap \dots$ onto a plane tree with internal vertices labeled $\cup$ or $\cap$ and leaves labeled $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots\,$, where internal vertex labels alternate away from the root. Given a tree with root $R$ whose children are subtrees $(T_1,\dots,T_k)$, $k\ge 2$, from left to right, we can read off the sequence $\ell(T)$ of the labels of the internal vertices of $T$ as follows:
$$
\ell(T)=(\ell(T_1),\ell(R),\ell(T_2),\ell(R),\ell(T_3),\dots,\ell(R),\ell(T_k)).
$$
We also let $|\ell(T)|$ be the length of $\ell(T)$ (which we we also define to be the \emph{size} of $T$) and give each internal vertex weight $z$, so that a tree $T$ has weight $z^{|\ell(T)|}$. We want to ensure that the sequence $\ell(T)$ is alternating, and then it is uniquely determined, since it starts with a $\cap$.

To ensure the labels alternate, $|\ell(T_i)|$ must be odd for all $i=2,\dots,k-1$, i.e. each subtree except the leftmost one and the rightmost one must be of odd size. For a tree $T$ with internal vertices, let $T_l$ and $T_r$ be its left and right subtrees, respectively. Moreover, since the root labels of all subtrees $T_i$, $i=1,\dots,k$, must be different from $\ell(R)$, we must have the following:

- the rightmost subtree $T_{1,r}$ of $T_1$ must be of even size,
- the leftmost subtree of $T_{k,l}$ of $T_k$ must be of even size,
- both the leftmost subtree $T_{i,l}$ and the rightmost subtree $T_{i,r}$ of each subtree $T_i$, $i=2,\dots,k-1$, must be of even size.

Define the following classes of trees:

- $\mathcal{E}=\{T\mid\ell(T)\text{ is alternating and } |\ell(T)| \text{ is even}\}$,
- $\mathcal{O}=\{T\mid\ell(T)\text{ is alternating and } |\ell(T)| \text{ is odd}\}$.

Then we can define the following subclasses of $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{E}$:

- $\mathcal{E}'_l=\{T\mid T\in\mathcal{E}, \text{ and } |\ell(T_l)| \text{ is even}\}$,
- $\mathcal{E}'_r=\{T\mid T\in\mathcal{E}, \text{ and } |\ell(T_r)| \text{ is even}\}$,
- $\mathcal{O}'=\{T\mid T\in\mathcal{O}, \text{ and } |\ell(T_l)|  \text{ and } |\ell(T_r)| \text{ are even}\}$.

Then, for $T\in\mathcal{O}$ with root degree $k\ge 2$, we have $T_2,\dots,T_{k-1}\in \mathcal{O}'$, and for $T_l=T_1$ and $T_r=T_k$, either $T_1,T_k\in \mathcal{E}'$, or $T_1,T_k\in \mathcal{O}'$.

Likewise, for $T\in\mathcal{E}$ with root degree $k\ge 2$, we have $T_2,\dots,T_{k-1}\in \mathcal{O}'$, and for $T_l=T_1$ and $T_r=T_k$, either $T_1\in \mathcal{E}'_l$, $T_k\in \mathcal{O}'$, or $T_1\in \mathcal{O}'$, $T_k\in \mathcal{E}'_r$.

Define the following generating functions:

- $E=E(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\mathcal{E}}{z^{|\ell(T)|}}$,
- $O=O(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\mathcal{O}}{z^{|\ell(T)|}}$,
- $O_1=O_1(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\mathcal{O}'}{z^{|\ell(T)|}}$,
- $E_{1,l}=E_{1,l}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\mathcal{E}'_l}{z^{|\ell(T)|}}$,
- $E_{1,r}=E_{1,r}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{T\in\mathcal{E}'_r}{z^{|\ell(T)|}}$.

By symmetry (reflecting the tree and switching all labels), we can see that $E_{1,l}=E_{1,r}=E_1=E_1(z)$ for some function $E_1$.

Then, from the above label sequence decompositions, we have the following relations between the above generating functions:
\begin{align*}
E&=1+\frac{2zE_1O_1}{1-zO_1}, &
O&=\frac{z(E_1^2+O_1^2)}{1-zO_1},\\
E_1&=1+\frac{zE_1O_1}{1-zO_1}, &
O_1&=\frac{zE_1^2}{1-zO_1}.
\end{align*}
This implies
$$
E=2E_1-1=E_1+\frac{zE_1O_1}{1-2zO_1}=\frac{E_1}{1-zO_1}.
$$
Likewise,
$$
O=O_1+\frac{zO_1^2}{1-zO_1}=\frac{O_1}{1-zO_1}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{O}{O_1}=\frac{O_1}{zE_1^2}, \quad \text{so} \quad O=z\left(\frac{O_1}{zE_1}\right)^2=z\left(\frac{E_1}{1-zO_1}\right)^2=zE^2.
$$
Moreover, we see that
$$
\frac{O_1}{zE_1}=E, \quad \text{so} \quad O_1=zEE_1=\frac{zE(1+E)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
E&=1+\frac{2zE_1O_1}{1-zO_1}= 1+z(2E_1)\frac{O_1}{1-zO_1}\\
&=1+z(1+E)O=1+z(1+E)(zE^2)\\
&=1+z^2(E^2+E^3),
\end{split}
$$
i.e. $E=E(z)=r_3(z^2)$ and $O=O(z)=zr_3^2(z^2)$, where $r_3=r_3(z)$ satisfies
$$
r_3=1+z(r_3^2+r_3^3),
$$
the recurrence relation for [A027307](https://oeis.org/A027307).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answer! I am so sorry to bother you for further questions, but I cannot verify/understand if I cannot understand the following: is it true that $l(T)$ is always an odd number (like $l(T)$ equals $2\times (\text{sets in }T)-1$)...? If $l(T)$ means how many sets are there in $T$, is it true that for $2,\dots,k-1$ the number of sets in $l(T)$ is even (instead of odd)...?

Comment: But I kind of understand the idea as I trying to understand the recursion. Thank you so much! I try to understand it and write it on my own!

Comment: @JetfiRex You’re welcome! $\ell(T)$ is the number of  $\cap/\cup$ operations in the string associated with the tree, i.e. the number of sets (leaves) minus $1$. Note that the number of times each internal node of $T$ is counted in $\ell(T)$ is the number of its children minus $1$.